# Smallest and Largest numbers

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Okay, I know there are several threads with similar questions to this, but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem on them. Everyone else is doing the same thing as me but their code works:

Heres the desired output:

```
How many numbers do you want to enter?
4
Enter a number:5
Enter a number:11
Enter a number:-2
Enter a number:3
Highest number is: 11
Lowest number is: -2
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void smallestLargest(){
    int highest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int num=0;
    Scanner sL = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
    int nums = sL.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<nums; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        num = sL.nextInt();
    }
    if (num > highest){
        num = highest;
    }
    if(num < lowest){
        num = lowest;
    }
    System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);

}
```

Heres the output I'm getting:

```
How many numbers do you want to enter?
4
Enter a number:5
Enter a number:11
Enter a number:-2
Enter a number:3
Highest number is: -2147483648
Lowest number is: 2147483647
```

I've got my friend on teamviewer trying to help since he's better at this than I am, but both of us are stumped. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check your braces

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `num = highest` you should do `highest = num`

Same thing for lowest.

And both `if`'s should be inside `for` loop (they must be done for every number entered)

Answer (score 1):

Try and read your program flow.  Basically, you want to read one Int at a time, then determine if that number you have read is either the highest number you have seen thus far or lowest.

You conditional branches should be inside your for loop.

```
for(...) {
    //read value
    //if num > highest, then highest = num
    //if num < lowest, then lowest = num
}
//print output, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. That was a silly mistake, But live and learn right?

Comment: Exactly. If that is the worst mistake you make in life, you're doing pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is these lines right here.

```
if (num > highest){
    num = highest;
}
if(num < lowest){
    num = lowest;
}
```

When if(num > highest) is true, you then set num equal to highest. What you really want to do is

```
if (num > highest){
    highest = num;
}
if(num < lowest){
    lowest = num;
}
```

This will now set lowest and highest to the correct number. However, you also need to set a loop in your code to check if highest and lowest needs to be update every time the user enters a number. The following code will get you the correct output.

```
for(int i=0; i<nums; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter a number:");
    num = sL.nextInt();

    if (num > highest){
        highest = num;
    }
    if(num < lowest){
        lowest = num;
    }
}
```